# self type annotation with dependecies: How to access inner methods

Tags: function, scala, inner-classes, self-type

```
object DatabaseConnection { this: LoginDevice =>
    val Connection = ...

    class LoginDevice {
        val prep = Connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME = ?")
        def login(username: String, password: String) = {
            prep.setString(1, username)
            val rs = prep.executeQuery
            if (!rs.next)
                throw User404
            new User(rs.getString("Name"), ...)             
        }
    }
}

object RequestHandler {
    type Request = (String, String)

    def handle(request: Request) = request._1 match {
        case "Login" => {
            val info = request._2.split(",")
            DatabaseConnection.login(info(0), info(1)) // SYNTAX ERROR
        }
        case _ => throw new Exception("Request type is not valid.")
    }
}
```

Now, I want to split my DatabaseConnection into "devices" that have their own prepared statements etc. They should all refer to this one `Connection` instance, though. I want to be able to call the inner function from outside.

What is the best way to do this without having to rename any of those functions?

btw sry for short text my hand is reaaally disabled atm.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to do DatabaseConnection.login(...) ? If that's the case you first need an instance of LoginDevice. As per your example there is no state in LoginDevice, so it can be an object.  Then in DatabaseConnection declare the functions like `val login = LoginDevice.login _ `.

Comment: This gets very close to the result I wanted. However, if I have like 10 devices, I have to declare each of those things twice and that seems redundant. Is there another way?

Comment: Would you mind showing the entire example with additional, say 10, devices so it's easier to figure out what you're doing? You certainly can't do `DatabaseConnection.login` inside `handle` as `login` is not a public method of the `DatabaseConnection` object.

Comment: will post tomorrow, i'm not very able to with my hand in the current state and i'm about to sleep now. thanks in advance though and good night. :)

Comment: Alright, I extended the example: http://pastebin.com/1gQDam3n. I don't want to mix up all those prepared statements as you see, and I don't want the redundancy that this `val login = LoginDevice.login _` entails (although it is gonna be my go-to solution if no other is provided) :)